# How to use a custom SMTP URL for Mailgun?

Tags: email, dns, smtp, gmail, mailgun

I use Mailgun for the outgoing emails of my customers and Cloudflare to manage DNS.

The problem is that my customers want to send emails using GMail as well, but I don't want them to know which service I am using.
Therefore, In case in the future I change the service, I don't want to contact all customers asking to change the parameters again.

Here is what I use:
[image: GMail SMTP config]

So I decided to use DNS for this: I created for each domain a new CNAME (smtp.mydomain.com) which points to smtp.eu.mailgun.org:
[image: Cloudflare DNS Setup]

Everything worked fine for few months by now, but from yesterday emails sent from GMail bounce back with this error: "TLS Negotiation failed, the certificate doesn't match the host".
I tried using other ports also, but still the same result.

If in GMail I use smtp.eu.mailgun.org instead of smtp.mydomain.com everything works fine again, so I guess the problem is in the DNS/Cloudflare configuration...

This is the report of the DNS Check of smtp.mydomain.com that I get from MXToolbox:
[image: DNS check from MXtoolbox.com]

Any idea on how to fix this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

As of April 2020, Google started enforcing TLS when sending email.

In the Gmail settings under Accounts and Imports, Edit your Send mail as Email settings.
Change your outgoing servername (SMTP Server) to smtp.hostprovider.com (mine was smtp.dreamhost.com). If you are using your website name, (mail.example.com), this will continue to fail.
I also updated the port number from 587 to Port 465

Hope this helps.